# New video card breaks GRUB auto boot to GUI

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, amd-graphics

I recently swapped out an old ATI video card for a newer Nvidia card. The card seems to be working just fine and I can get a GUI with some effort.

However, the new video card seems to have broke GRUB. When I boot up, the GUI is no longer automatically selected. Instead, all I get is a flashing cursor. I tried switching to one of the other terminals (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) but there is still a flashing cursor. Although I can successfully switch to the GUI via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and log in.

How can I fix GRUB and boot up to the GUI directly again?

Thanks

Comment: having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be the open source drivers did not work with my Nvidia card. After installing Nvidia's proprietary drivers, the system would boot normally.

In order to enter the keyphrase to mount the encrypted drive, I just keyed over (right arrow key) until I got the usual purple screen.